# Spring bean reload with Archaius

Tags: java, spring, netflix-archaius

I'm trying to use Archaius with my Spring application to reload dynamic system properties without having to do a full restart of the application. I'm planning on implementing this using Archaius' callback mechanism. Once Archaius detects a change, in the callback method I plan to do a bean refresh to pick up the new property changes.

The problem is, there are a few singleton beans that are created on start-up which are using the property I want to reload. I also have a few classes which autowires this singleton bean.

Is there a way of doing a refresh of the bean and all its dependencies without perform a restart or an applicationContext.refresh()?

Or does Archaius have a built-in library which can help with Spring integration?